# How to parse local JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON file `jsquiz.json` that contains:

```
{
"firstname": "Kane",
"secondname": "Brown",
"sports": ["basketball","hockey"]
}
```

I have a separate file in the same directory `jsquiz.html` where I would like the information from the JSON file to be displayed:

```
...
<ul>
  <li id="first"></li>
  <li id="last"></li>
  <li id="sport1"></li>
  <li id="sport2"></li>
</ul>
...
```

From reading various sources I think I have to create a JavaScript object out of the JSON file using the `.parse()` method but I'm at a bit of a loss as to how I can import the JSON information from an external file?

Any help appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I don't even know where to start with a JSON file. The first time I succeeded with using an object literal in an external javascript file.

Comment: Retrieve the file using AJAX and then parse its content by using `JSON.parse()`. Then you can insert all values in your template and add it to the DOM.

Comment: So I can use AJAX to 'import' the file even if it is stored locally, and then use `JSON.parse()`. I think I get it, I'll have to look up AJAX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load data from a JSON file using an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/XMLHttpRequest/Usar_XMLHttpRequest).

This example will block until it is loaded:

```
var yourJSONObject = {} // will later be filled with the data
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', 'http://www.example.com/jsquiz.json', false); 
req.send(null);
if(req.status == 200) // 200 request status
  yourJSONObject = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
}
```

This example will load in the background:

```
var yourJSONObject = {} // will later be filled with the data
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', 'http://www.example.com/jsquiz.json', true); 
req.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
  if (req.readyState == 4) {
      yourJSONObject = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
  }
};
req.send(null);
```

Unfortunately not all browsers allow XMLHttpRequest's to local files by default. Some browsers might need a little configuration change to be persuaded to allow it.

Answer (score 1):

change the json file to be a valid js variable:

```
var jsonData = {
 "firstname": "Kane",
 "secondname": "Brown",
 "sports": ["basketball","hockey"]
}
```

then in your page :

```
<script src="jsquiz.json"></script>
```

now in your page after its loaded you can use a variable nameed `jsonData`

Comment: Would this be considered JSON though? Is it not just an object literal?

Comment: when you load a js file the content are loaded as they are so yes jsonData is a JSON object

Comment: This pattern is usually referred to as "JSONP" (JSON with padding). It's quite dangerous to load from a source you don't control, but it's safe when you trust the source.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't access local files so easily.
You must either include that file in the page (like Exlord says), or export it over HTTP using some web server and load it using jQuery (like henje says) or directly (like Philipp).

If you have Python you could export the file using:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

(other tools can help you here also).

Answer (score 0):

You could request the file with AJAX, as long as it is in your web directory (with JQuery)

```
$.ajax({url: "jsquiz.json",})
  .done(function(response) {
    data = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Then you only have to create a new DOMElement and add it.

Comment: You seem to use some kind of library. Considering that the OP didn't mention any libraries, you should mention which one is needed to use this example.

Comment: directly after I posted I recognized this myself and added that is utilizes JQuery, but thanks for the reminder.